# Where is the safest place to call unregisterContentObserver?

Tags: android, provider

In my apps, I call registerContentObserver in the activity's onCreate(). Currently I call unregister...() in onDestroy(). I realize that onDestroy() is not guaranteed to complete so it is possible that sometimes my unregister call never gets executed.

Is it better to move the unregister to onStop() and, along with that, move the resister to onStart()? Or is it safe the way it is. That is, does Android clean up any dangling registrations when an activity terminates?

I've even read on some posts that onStop() is not guaranteed to execute. I don't know if this is true, though. (I guess, in an extreme case, it has to be true - if your app never completes its execution of onStop(), Android will have to terminate it anyway.)

Comment: If `onDestroy()` is not called, either you crashed with an unhandled exception, or your process is terminated. In the latter case, your `ContentObserver` goes away too.

Comment: Ok, if you're sure about that, then it should be safe to call unregister in onDestroy() provided that one also calls setDefaultUncaughtException() and unregisters there, if needed. Thanks.